# SELECT FROM VALUES (x), (y) - only if VALUE not equal to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I select from a list of values but exclude that value if it equals 0, something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(score) FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2)) AS score(score)) AS MS
```

So the result of this query should be 1, as we've excluded 0.

Comment: `WHERE score.score != 0`? Or perhaps `> 0`?

Comment: Thanks Larnu, it works. I tried this originally but didn't know I had to do score.score.

Comment: I would personally suggest, then, tjat naming your table (construct) and column the same was the *real* problem here. If you'd showed us your attempt we could have explained your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three methods:

```
SELECT MIN(score.score) AS MS
FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2)) score(score)
WHERE score.score <> 0;

SELECT MIN(NULLIF(score.score, 0)) AS MS
FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2)) score(score);

SELECT TOP (1) score.score AS MS
FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2)) score(score)
WHERE score.score <> 0
ORDER BY score.score;
```

Note that all of these are syntactically correct.  I assume the `AS MS` is intended to name the result of the `MIN()`.

Comment: Yes it is, thanks, I changed my query to the 1st method as it's a little neater.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation. In SQL Server you have `NULLIF`:

```
SELECT MIN(NULLIF(score,0))
FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2)) AS score(score)) AS MS
```

In standard SQL there is `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN score = 0 THEN NULL ELSE score END)
FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2)) AS score(score)) AS MS
```

**UPDATE:** Oops, see the request comments. Larnu is right of course. Just use a `WHERE` clause.